# How to apply async task into this

Tags: android, android-asynctask

After a few hours of trying I still cannot figure out how to incorporate an asynctask into the below code.

I have tried threading which didn't work either. All I want to do is to run the scan in the background and show a progressbar.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

private void populateView() {

    List<PackageInfo> adPackages = getAdPackages();
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(adPackages.size());
    for(PackageInfo pkg : adPackages) {
        Map<String, String> attrs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attrs.put("App Name", pm.getApplicationLabel(pkg.applicationInfo).toString());
        attrs.put("Package Name", pkg.packageName);
        data.add(attrs);
    }

    String[] from = new String[] {
        "App Name",
        "Package Name"
    };
    int[] to = new int[] {
        android.R.id.text1,
        android.R.id.text2
    };
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this, data, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, from, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    mPackages = adPackages;
}
```

.

```
private List<PackageInfo> getAdPackages() {
    Set<PackageInfo> adPackages = new HashSet<PackageInfo>();

//[...]
    List<ApplicationInfo> appInfos = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    for(ApplicationInfo appInfo : appInfos) {

        try {

            //[Heavy Stuff]

    return new ArrayList<PackageInfo>(adPackages);

   }
}
```

Comment: which part you want to run in Async, i suppose getting package loop `in onCreate`

Comment: I'm trying to run it at `private List<PackageInfo> getAdPackages() `  as long it will not cause ANR and it will allow to update UI thread to show the progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done.

You have to move your `getPackages` logic to `doInBackground` of `AsyncTask`.
And you have to call `publishProgress` from `doInBackground` when you want to update progress bar.

Once `doInBackground` is done, then `onPostExecute` is called. Put all the logic for data for adapter and adapter itself in it. Set the adapter also in the function.

Below are few reference docs you can refer:

[Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
[Worker Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads)

Here is some sample:

```
 private class GetPackageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<PackageInfo>> {
 protected List<PackageInfo> doInBackground(URL... urls) {

     // Put your code of getPackages in here

     // You can call publish like it is done below
     //for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     //    totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
     //    publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
     //}

     // adPackages is what you returning from your getPackages function
     return adPackages;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(List<PackageInfo> result) {
     // Here you will have all the setAdapter related code
 }
}
```

onCreate will contain

new DownloadFilesTask().execute();

Comment: Sound very complicated,  I will try,  do you mind help me? I will pay you

Comment: Hope now it will be less complicated...well I reply on stackoverflow just for fun...you have to write `setProgressPercent(progress[0])` function which will update the `ProgressBar`

Comment: Thanks for your help , this is what i have done http://pastebin.com/nvXD6YHv  but still there is a single line error at `protected List<PackageInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {` did i miss anything?

Comment: Updated the paste at : http://pastebin.com/Gg4n95uD ...removed `private List<PackageInfo> getAdPackages() {` and changed `List<PackageInfo> adPackages = getAdPackages();` to `List<PackageInfo> adPackages = result;`...this should work now.