# How to load a listview with a CustomCursorAdapter in the background and with a progressbar?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm using a `CustomCursorAdapter` (extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`) which binds the cursor data to a `ListView` in my main activity but it is very slow.  So I want to load it in the background and show a `ProgressBar`.  The problem is that the content is shown at once, so I don't have a chance to show a `ProgressBar` to the user.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AsyncTask to do this. Pls refer to this question:

[How to apply async task into this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8366211/525978)